# How to read several files to array of hashtable and get corresponding file name

Tags: java

I want to read all files in a folder, each file content will be read into a hashtable. Then I need to compare each word in a text file with each of this hashtable. If that word match any word in that hashtable, a variable will be named after the corresponding file name that created that hashtable.
Now I have two difficulties:

1.How to have a list of hashtable for every files in the folder.

2.How to named the variable when finding the word in that hashtable.

I try this code and it works for 1 file, 1 hashtable.

```
 Hashtable HashTableName;

  public String namebymatching;


  // compare the spannedText for words in each dictionary in folder
  public OneExtractor() throws IOException {
    super();
    // location
    HashTableName = new Hashtable();


    FilenameFilter ff = new OnlyExt("txt");
    File folder = new File("/Folder Path/");
    File[] files = folder.listFiles(ff);
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(files[i].getPath());
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String st = "", str = " ";
      while ((st = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str += st + " ";
      }
      map.put(files[i].getName(), str);
    }
    Set set = map.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();

      BufferedReader br = null;
      try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "/Folder Path"+me.getKey()));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PersonExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        HashTableName.put(line.toLowerCase(), 1);
        while (line != null) {
          line = br.readLine();
          if (!line.isEmpty())
            HashTableName.put(line.toLowerCase(), 1);
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {

      } finally {
        try {
          br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(PersonExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  private boolean isHashTableName(String s) {
    return HashTableName.containsKey(s.toLowerCase());
  }

  ///Extension  
  public static class OnlyExt implements FilenameFilter {
    String ext;

    public OnlyExt(String ext) {
      this.ext = "." + ext;
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      return name.endsWith(ext);
    }
  }
// Find word match :
   String word = //some function here to extract word;

    namebymatching = "NOT" + filename; //filename should be here
    if (isHashTableName(spannedText))
      namebymatching = "ISPARTOF" +filename;//filename should be here
```

Comment: First thing use a `HashMap` if you don't need synchronization .

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `Hashtable` to manage your collection of `Hashtable`s!! If you want to be slightly more modern, use a `HashMap` instead. You can use an outer hash table that maps files to inner hash tables, and the inner hash tables can then be analyzed. For each file you find, add an entry to the outer hash table, then for each entry, do the process you have already figured out for that file.

Comment: I think I already apply HashMap in my above code. "    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
" but when I extend this code for my purpose above, I can see the performance is so slow. It really take like a day without showing me the result...